# Enable/Disable a group of task at the time of Release Management in Visual Studio Online

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, azure-devops, release-management

[image]
How to enable/disable a group of task in Visual Studio Online at the time of Release Management by using global/local variable?

can we enable/disable by using Manual Intervention task ,if yes then how?

Answer (score 0):

It is currently not posible to enable or disable tasks during a build.

You can request/vote for this feature on http://visualstudio.uservoice.com

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible now, I submit a user voice here: [Enable/disable task and task group by using variable](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services/suggestions/18390064-enable-disable-task-and-task-group-by-using-variab)

The workaround is that you can clone the release definition (right click a release definition > Clone), then remove some tasks or task groups and save it, after that you can create release with corresponding release definition per to detail scenario.

Comment: can we enable/disable group task using PowerShell script ?

Comment: @DevendraPratapSingh No, we can't.

Comment: @starain-MSFT Sure you can. I do things like that via the REST API all the time. GET the build definition, flip the enabled flag, PUT the modified definition back.

Comment: @DanielMann Yes, but it is at the design time and need to modify definition, it's better that we can control it by using variable, then just change the variable value when queue build or change the variable value during the runtime.